# Heliohost website deployment problem. not redirecting

Tags: php, deployment, web-applications

I made a php website. It has log in mechanism. I was able to upload it Heliohost but when I logged in to my web app, it is not redirecting to where it is supposed to redirect. What might be the problem?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the log in
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiOJP.png
When I log in, it just shows blank

same goes with 000webhost. The log in page appears but after i log in, nothing happens.

Comment: I inspected the webpage. it says
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
Then it shows this line
$.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator

Comment: Inspected again. <b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd1/324/15495324/public_html/index.php:8) in <b>/storage/ssd1/324/15495324/public_html/resource/backend.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />

Comment: If you search that warning error message you'll find a lot of similar questions. But, generally it means you're outputting data to your page before you are redirecting. You should always redirect before outputting any data. By outputting data I mean anything that displays anything on the webpage with PHP code, including things like `var_dump()` and `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for the log in btw:

```
public function logIn($user,$pass){
    $vrfy = $this->conDB();
    $qry = "select * from users";
    $res = $vrfy->query($qry);
    //echo 'alert("Invalid Username or Passwordasd");';
    if($res)
            while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
                if($row['username']==$user && $row['password']==$pass)
                if($user=='admin'){
                        $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                        header('location:resource/addash.php');
                                  }
                        
                    else if($user=='associate'){
                        $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                        header('location:resource/asdash.php');
                                               }
            }
        
     echo 'alert("Invalid Username or Password");';
}
```